# Miscellaneous Questions involving Tensor Products, Exact Sequences, and Algebras

Tags: tensor-products, exact-sequence, algebras

Let R
  be a ring (unital, though not necessarily commutative, and let: \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \hookrightarrow & M & \overset{f}{\hookrightarrow} & N & \overset{g}{\twoheadrightarrow} & P & \twoheadrightarrow & 0\end{array}
 be a short exact sequence of left R
 -modules.

1) Let Q
  be a right R
 -module. Consider the exact sequence:$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
Q\otimes_{R}M & \overset{\textrm{Id}\otimes f}{\longrightarrow} & Q\otimes_{R}N & \overset{\textrm{Id}\otimes g}{\rightarrow} & Q\otimes_{R}P & \twoheadrightarrow & 0\end{array}$$

Show that $\textrm{Id}\otimes f$
  is injective whenever Q
  is a projective right R
 -module. Give an example where $\textrm{Id}\otimes f$
  is not injective.

2) Let Q
  be a left R
 -module. Consider the exact sequence: $$0\hookrightarrow\textrm{Hom}_{R}\left(Q,M\right)\begin{array}{cccc}
\overset{f_{*}}{\longrightarrow} & \textrm{Hom}_{R}\left(Q,N\right) & \overset{g_{*}}{\rightarrow} & \textrm{Hom}_{R}\left(Q,P\right)\end{array}$$

Show that $g_{*}$
  is surjective whenever Q
  is a projective left R
 -module.

3) Let $\phi:R\rightarrow S$
  be a homomorphism of commutative rings. Show that there is an isomorphism of S
 -algebras: $$R\left[x_{1},\ldots,x_{N}\right]\otimes_{R}S\cong S\left[x_{1},\ldots,x_{N}\right]$$

I've been working probably a total of ten hours on these three problems, all to no avail whatsoever. I've been given hints by my instructor, (such as for the first problem, to consider first the case where Q
  is a free right R-module), but I haven't been able to get anywhere with them.

As someone with a penchant for pedantry, good pedagogy, specificity concreteness, and explicit constructions, much of what we have been doing in algebra as of late has left me feeling adrift and at a loss. I spend hours trying to come up with a formula for the isomorphism in (3), only for the professor to enigmatically refer to “cokernels” or “the universal property of S
 -algebras”—the former of which I know not how to use; the latter of which we never even discussed in class (or, if we did, we discussed it under a different name, and no one bothered to point out that it was equivalent to a “universal property of S-algebras”.

Help (preferably in the form of solutions that I can spend time trying to wrap my head around) would be INFINITELY appreciated.

Comment: What's your definition of a projective module?

Comment: Essentially Hungerford's. M is projective if, for every surjective R-linear map g:N—>N' and every R-linear map f:M—>N', there is a lift f':M—>N so that g o f' = f.

Comment: So question 2 results directly from the definition.

Comment: I have tried playing around with the triangle diagrams for HOURS, and I cannot see how to get it to work right. For me, this "direct result", at present, seems highly non-trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First statement

Sketch of proof.

1. It holds for $Q=R$ (as right $R$-module)
2. If it holds for modules $Q_\alpha$, then it also holds for $\bigoplus_\alpha Q_\alpha$
3. If it holds for the module $Q$, then it also holds for every direct summand of $Q$.

Since a projective module is a direct summand of a free module, putting together 1, 2 and 3 gives the proof.

A counterexample is with $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=N=\mathbb{Z}$, $f$ the multiplication by $2$, $P=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $g$ the canonical projection. If you take $Q=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the map $\mathrm{Id}\otimes f$ is the zero map.

## Second statement

This is just a reformulation of the definition of projective module.

## Third statement

We can be reduce to the case when $N=1$, applying induction for the general case. I'm afraid that the isomorphism $R[x]\otimes_R S\to S[x]$ is essentially the universal property of the tensor product together with the universal property of the polynomial ring in one indeterminate, but here's a sketch.

You want to show that the ring $R[x]\otimes_RS$ satisfies the required property for being $S[x]$. Suppose $f\colon S\to T$ is any ring homomorphism and $b\in T$. You want to prove that there exists a unique ring homomorphism $f_b\colon R[x]\otimes_RS\to T$ such that

1. $f_b\circ j=f$, where $j\colon S\to R[x]\otimes_RS$ is defined by $j(s)=1\otimes s$;
2. $f_b(x\otimes 1)=b$

Consider $f\circ\phi\colon R\to T$. Then, by the properties of $R[x]$, there exists a unique ring homomorphism $g\colon R[x]\to T$ such that $g(r)=f\circ\phi(r)$, for $r\in R$, and $g(x)=b$.

Now define $f_b\colon R[x]\otimes_RS\to T$ by
$$
f_b(P\otimes s)=g(P)f(s)
$$
(use the universal property of tensor products) which is a ring homomorphism (prove it). Then $f_b(x\otimes 1)=g(x)1=b$ as required. Also
$$
f_b\circ j(s)=f_b(1\otimes s)=g(1)f(s)=f(s)
$$
Complete the proof by showing the uniqueness of $f_b$.

Comment: The proofs of (1) and (2) seem to involve diagrams—and diagrammatic reasoning is not my strong suit. Which diagrams do I use (tensor product universal property? Projective module universal property?), and what entries go in the corners of the triangles?


/ / [You want to prove that there exists a unique ring homomorphism] - - - This is alien reasoning to me. When I get asked to prove that A is isomorphic to B, my experience tells me that I do so by constructing a map between them which is bijective and which preserves the given structure. Is there no way to do that here?

Comment: Also, what is a counter-example for (2)?

Comment: @MCS It may be alien to you, but this is algebra. Yes, there is a more direct proof. For the counterexample, take any nonprojective module. The same sequence as for statement 1 and $Q=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ would suffice.

Comment: And in your proof of (3), what is the map g? I have never heard of a universal property of polynomial rings. That being said, In my attempts to prove (3), I tried defining a map $f\left(P\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\otimes s\right)=\tilde{\phi}\left\{ P\right\} \left(\mathbf{x}\right)s$ as my candidate for the isomorphism, where $\tilde{\phi}$ is the map that ${\phi}$ induces on the R polynomial ring. But the bilinear multiplicative condition seems to fall apart here, because ${\phi}$ gets in the way of nicely manipulating the scalar coefficients. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: [Yes, there is a more direct proof.] - - - Which would be?

Comment: @MCS That's for you to find. The ingredients are in the abstract proof.

Comment: Is there a place where I could go to find it? Or could you do me the courtesy of telling me? I've been working myself to the bone on these problems, traveling in endless circles. Concrete proofs to motivate the abstract proofs would be a major help. I'm afraid I'm not quite competent at parsing the abstractions and coming away with something concrete. And I find that knowing the answer forthwith is a far more instructive and efficient use of my time than spending hours traveling in circles to no avail.

Comment: Could you please give (or link me to) the direct proof? Please? I'm desperate. I've been losing sleep over this. Everywhere I turn, I get the same dismissive response from people, and it's been causing me a great deal of grief.

Comment: @MCS Can you define $S[x]\to R[x]\otimes_RS$ by $s_0+\dots+s_nx^n\mapsto 1\otimes s_0+x\otimes s_1+\dots+x^n\otimes s_n$? Then go on.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much!